# Checking the list of suspended users

Tags: discussion, user-suspension

After searching, I found the [list of suspended users for mathematics stack exchange site](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/104095/suspended-users).

How can I search for our main site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I copied the code and composed the query for Hinduism stack exchange.
See: https://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/query/1418328/suspended-users

Comment: Just a general disclaimer: Stack Exchange Data Explorer is updated weekly, so there may be a discrepancy between the data and the real situation.